# error: failed to select a version for `tree-sitter`. gpui.rs

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I'm trying to create simple ui program using [gpui.rs](https://www.gpui.rs/).

Below is the Cargo.toml -

```bash
[package]
name = "gpui-first-look-duanne-bester"
version = "0.1.0"
edition = "2021"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
gpui = { git = "https://github.com/zed-industries/zed" }
assets = { git = "https://github.com/zed-industries/zed" }
theme = { git = "https://github.com/zed-industries/zed" }
settings = { git = "https://github.com/zed-industries/zed" }
ui = { git = "https://github.com/zed-industries/zed" }
```

Below is my `main.rs` file -

```rust
use gpui::*;
use assets::Assets;
use settings::{default_settings, SettingsStore};
use theme::{ThemeRegistry, ThemeSettings};
use seetings::Settings;

struct HelloWorld {
    text: SharedString,
}

impl Render for HelloWorld {
    fn render(&mut self, _cx: &mut ViewContext<Self>) -> impl IntoElement {
        div()
            .flex()
            .bg(rgb(0x2e7d32))
            .size_full()
            .justify_center()
            .items_center()
            .text_xl()
            .text_color(rgb(0xffffff))
            .child(format!("Hello, {}!", &self.text))
    }
}

fn main() {
    App::new().run(|cx: &mut AppContext| {

        let theme_name = "One Dark";

        let mut store = SettingsStore::default();
        store.set_default_settings(default_settings().as_ref(), cx)
            .unwrap();
        cx.set_global(store);

        theme::init(themes_to_load: theme::LoadThemes::All(Box::new(Assets)), cx);

        let theme_registry :&ThemeRegistry = cx.global::<ThemeRegistry>();
        let mut theme_settings: ThemeSettings = ThemeSettings::get_global(cx).clone();
        theme_settings.active_theme = theme_registry.get(&theme_name).unwrap();
        ThemeSettings::override_global(theme_settings, cx);

        cx.open_window(WindowOptions::default(), |cx| {
            cx.new_view(|_cx| HelloWorld {
                text: "World".into(),
            })
        });
    });
}
```

When I do `cargo run` I get below error -

> cargo run
> Updating git repository `https://github.com/zed-industries/zed`
>
> Updating crates.io index
>
> Updating git repository `https://github.com/zed-industries/font-kit`
>
> Updating git repository `https://github.com/DioxusLabs/taffy`
>
> Updating git repository `https://github.com/kvark/blade`
>
> Updating git repository `https://github.com/zed-industries/bromberg_sl2`
>
> error: failed to select a version for `tree-sitter`.
>
> ... required by package `settings v0.1.0 (https://github.com/zed-industries/zed#0ce5cdc4)`
>
> ... which satisfies git dependency `settings` of package `gpui-first-look-duanne-bester v0.1.0 (/Users/rnatarajan/Documents/Coding/others/gpui-first-look-duanne-bester)`
>
> versions that meet the requirements `^0.20` are: 0.20.10, 0.20.9, 0.20.8, 0.20.7, 0.20.6, 0.20.5, 0.20.4, 0.20.3, 0.20.2, 0.20.1, 0.20.0
>
> the package `settings` depends on `tree-sitter`, with features: `wasm` but `tree-sitter` does not have these features.
>
> failed to select a version for `tree-sitter` which could resolve this conflict

Any idea what is going wrong here? How can I fix this error?
My project is in github [here](https://github.com/rajcspsg/gpui-first-look-duanne-bester.git).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an error not in your code. The current contents of the `Cargo.toml` from https://github.com/zed-industries/zed include:

```ini
[workspace.dependencies]
...
tree-sitter = { version = "0.20", features = ["wasm"] }
```

which is self-contradictory, because the `wasm` feature wasn't introduced until incompatible version 0.21. This cannot be compiled. So, why doesn't this break everybody? Because the `Cargo.toml` also contains a [patch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/overriding-dependencies.html) which overrides this dependency:

```ini
[patch.crates-io]
tree-sitter = { git = "https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter", rev = "4294e59279205f503eb14348dd5128bd5910c8fb" }
```

Therefore, *when building the `zed` workspace*, the `tree-sitter` source is fetched from that particular Git commit (which does have a `wasm` feature declared). But patches are ignored when you are merely depending on a library, not building/developing *in* that specific workspace.

So, the error is in the `zed` repository, for your purposes. If they wish to support use of their libraries in the way you're attempting, then they should replace the `patch` with a plain `git` dependency:

```rust
[workspace.dependencies]
...
tree-sitter = { git = "https://github.com/tree-sitter/tree-sitter", rev = "4294e59279205f503eb14348dd5128bd5910c8fb", features = ["wasm"] }
```

I don't see any explanation of why they *don't* do this — there is no comment, and [the commit which added the patch](https://github.com/zed-industries/zed/commit/1f16c68e6bef52c6fe9cb20d5be46484da2be421) didn't explain either. So perhaps this is just an oversight and they'd welcome a PR to simplify it — or perhaps there's a non-obvious reason it's necessary.

As a workaround, you could include the `[patch.crates-io]` that I quoted above in *your* `Cargo.toml`.

Comment: I added the above dependency still I see the same problem.

Comment: error: failed to select a version for `tree-sitter`.
    ... required by package `settings v0.1.0 (https://github.com/zed-industries/zed#f1791589)`
    ... which satisfies git dependency `settings` of package `gpui-first-look-duanne-bester v0.1.0 (/Users/e143823/Documents/Coding/others/gpui-first-look-duanne-bester)`
versions that meet the requirements `^0.20` are: 0.20.10, 0.20.9, 0.20.8, 0.20.7, 0.20.6, 0.20.5, 0.20.4, 0.20.3, 0.20.2, 0.20.1, 0.20.0
the package `settings` depends on `tree-sitter`, with features: `wasm` but `tree-sitter` does not have these features.

Comment: @user51 The problem is in the `Cargo.toml` in the `zed` repository. You cannot fix it by adding dependencies. You could, however, work around it by copying the `[patch.crates-io]` section into your own `Cargo.toml`.